# Angular 5+, Http Interceptor Response - Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'

Tags: angular5, httpresponse, angular-http-interceptors

If anyone gets an error while working with Http Interceptors stating :

" Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable>'". I've posted the solution below which worked for me.

My packages were:

rxjs - 5.5.6,

@angular/core - 5.2.0,

typescript - 2.4.1

Comment: I also get this error when I open project in visual studio and in VS code IDE it don't give this error but in any case it don't stop project from running

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution that helped me to catch response in an Interceptor.

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
    let body = res.body;
     if(body){
        console.log(“data “, body);
     }
      return res; 
  }),
  catchError((error: any) => {
  console.log(“error “, error);
  return Observable.throw(error);
}));
```